# Diffuclty using java-gnome in maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml, gnome

I am using Netbeans 12 IDE on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and have installed java-gnome using command :

`sudo apt-get install libjava-gnome-java`

I created a small project to test the notification with the main class code as following :

```
package com.mycompany.notifytest;
import org.gnome.gtk.Gtk;
import org.gnome.notify.Notify;
import org.gnome.notify.Notification;
/**
 *
 * @author nbs
 */
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gtk.init(args);
        Notify.init("NotifyTest");
        Notification n = new Notification("Notify Test", "Test Passed !", "");
        n.show();
        
    }
    
}
```

Now whenever I run the project using F6 the notification is shown and the output is:

```
cd /home/nbs/NetBeansProjects/NotifyTest; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /snap/netbeans/41/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.notifytest.Main" -Dexec.executable=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

----------------------< com.mycompany:NotifyTest >----------------------
Building NotifyTest 1.0-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/com/java.gnome/1.0/java.gnome-1.0.pom
The POM for org.com:java.gnome:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available

--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ NotifyTest ---
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  10.252 s
Finished at: 2021-03-04T13:37:04+05:30
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But after building the project when I try to run the .jar file from terminal, the problem is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gnome/gtk/Gtk
    at com.mycompany.notifytest.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gnome.gtk.Gtk
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Your resulting jar does not contain the needed classes/jar

Comment: How can I overcome this problem? I think the java-gnome dependency is not present in the jar since if I add a print statemt in the code, it is executed.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything how you build your application nor do I know how your pom file looks like so ? What have you tried so far? How does your pom file look like? Which Java version/Maven version etc you are using?